# Fixing a corrupt HTM file

Tags: html, html5

I was working on some HTM files at my school, and when I go to open them up later to finalize them, I get scrambled corrupt text (like what you would see if you opened up an executable in notepad.

Sample section (cannot copy from file for some reason):
tGY uyT=♣
─◄S↓N#     isoxui83§/4S§▐5‼◄♦

the code looks like the above but with different characters. is there a way to fix this or do I have to redo all four of my assignments?

Comment: You just learned an important lesson.  Save your work in three places.  In addition... learn version control.  (Take a look at Git.  It's easy to use, even for small projects like this.)  In any case, voting to move this over to SuperUser.com.  There are some file recovery tools, but it looks pretty hopeless if this is what you see.

Comment: HTML is text, looks like you didn't corrupt it but overwrote I.

Comment: i guess it is futile to try to recover my files then? it is kind of hard to do a reversion when  my prof. requires us to use only notepad++. i guess i'll just have to redo them.

Comment: @Brad, I think important lesson here is to stop using floppy disks..

Comment: @valentinas lol @ floppy disks.

Comment: @7c00h, Notepad++ has nothing to do with this.  Besides, you can use whatever you want.  It's not like it is possible to tell what was used to make your files.  Blaming your tools is not the way to understand and fix your mistakes.

Comment: joe, it is corrupt as the html code itself is just scrambled ASCII characters.

Comment: @brad i understand that. however, from my professor "IF you use any other software, as i can check, other than noitepad++ on this project, you will get a ZERO. no ifs ands or buts."

Comment: @7c00h, Sounds like you need to go to a new school. Your professor has no way of knowing what you use for your editor, unless you're using something like Dreamweaver or Front Page, which interject lots of other crap into your HTML.

Comment: Just to add - GitHub for Windows [http://windows.github.com/] make version control super easy.

Comment: @valentinas, who said anything about floppy disks? They’re using a 1GB flash-drive.

Answer (score 2):

**It's entirely possible that notepad++ is misdetecting the character encoding of your document.**  First save off a copy of your existing document (using explorer, not file-->save as)

Then try cycling though the encodings available under the encoding menu.  This can acually happen with any document or text editor.  It usually happens if you cut and paste certain special characters to the beginning of your documents or concatenate two encoding schemes together.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions
1
Open the corrupt file with a different program. For example, if a Microsoft Word file appears to be corrupt, try opening it with Notepad or a similar word processing program. Html files try notepadd++, notepad, dreamweaver.

2
Open the program you normally use to view the file and activate the program's internal repair function. For example, in Microsoft Office files select "Alt" and "F" and then the letter "O." Select the file you wish to open. Click the down arrow next to "Open" and select "Open and Repair."

3
Right click on the file and select "Copy." Browse to a new location, right click and select "Paste." This may clear up the corruption and allow you to open the file.

4
Double click "My Computer". Right click on the drive with the corrupt file and select "Properties." Click the "Tools" tab and then "Error Checking." Click "Start," and Check Disk will find and repair any errors on the drive. When Check Disk is finished, attempt to open the file.

Hope this helps, let me know if it doesn't

P.S Always remember to back up your work, have you tried restoring to a previous restore point on your computer also?